# Is it possible to reference a VSTS Build variable directly into a Xamarin project code?

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

Currently exploring an option to configure app secret in VSTS build variable and then reference the build variable within in the xamarin.Android project. Is that even possible? I know that we can use a script to update the project from the build variable. But looking for a simple and direct approach. The idea is to have different app secret for different build configuration.

Anyone have any experience in this area?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use build variable to replace the secret you defined in your Xamarin.android code (assume the secret is stored in `MainActivity.cs`).

#### Option 1: use [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension task

- Add a variable (such as `password`) in **Variables Tab**, and set the value as what you want to use in your code.
- Add the **Replace Tokens task** in your build definition.

  Root directory: where your `MainActivity.cs` stored in or the parent directory.

  Target files: `**\ MainActivity.cs`

  Empty value: `password`
- Change the secret setting as `secret="#{password}#";` in your code. The task will replace the part start with `#{` and end with `}#`.

#### Option 2: use PowerShell task

Assume the secret defined in your code as `secret="password";`.

- Add a variable (such as `token`) in **variables Tab**, and set the value as what you want to replace.
- Add **PowerShell task** in your build definition.

  Type: inline Script

  Inline Script:

  `$path="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\project\project\ MainActivity.cs"
  (Get-Content $path) -replace "password",$(token) | out-file $path`

For MAC, you can use the shell script as below:

`cd /to/the/path/the/file/exist
find . -type f -name "MainActivity.cs" | xargs sed -i '' 's/password/$(token)/g'`

Comment: Thank you. But we are using Mac Build agent to build the Xamarin.Android project. Do you have any example Bash Shell script to replace it? Will the extension work in Mac environment? as some of the build tasks can only work in Windows environment.

Comment: I added the shell script in the end of my answer. And sorry for that I have no mac pc available for current time, you can test by yourself. It may works for mac since the main function is find and replace (no difference with other OS).